# magento2 send email programmatically without template

Tags: magento2.3, email, email-templates, programmatically, email-scheduler

**I want to send custom email programmatically without any template.**

In magento 1, I used below script to do same thing.

```
$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
$mail->setToName('xxx');
$mail->settoemail('xxx@yyy.com');
$mail->setBody($html);
$mail->setSubject('Test email : '.$fieldss['o']);
$mail->setfromemail('from@yopmail.com');
$mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format
$mail->setBodyHTML($html);  // your content or message
try{ 
    $mail->send();
}catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();exit;
}
```

Here, In magento 2 I used below code but it gives error.

```
$objectManager = $this->getObjectManager();
$transport = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder');
$transport->addTo('xxx@yyy.com', 'Hiren Shah');
//$transport->settoemail('hiren.shah@healthtrader.com');
//$transport->setBody($html);
$transport->setSubject('Test email : '.$fieldss['o']);
$transport->setFrom('from@yopmail.com');
$transport->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format
$transport->setBodyHTML($html);  // your content or message
$transport->getTransport();
try { 
    $transport->sendMessage();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();exit;
}
```

But this gives me error `Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder\Interceptor::setSubject()`

How to send custom email without template? Please give me code sample.

Comment: can you advise me on this I have tried this on Magento 2 but getting an error Fatal error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Zend_Mail' not found in /srv/public_html/pub/test.php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Magento 2: The simplest way I found to send a plain text - use Zend1 mail

```
    $to = ['email1@test.com', 'email2@test.com'];
    $email = new \Zend_Mail();
    $email->setSubject("Feedback email");
    $email->setBodyText($body);
    $email->setFrom($from, $nameFrom);
    $email->addTo($to, $nameTo);
    $email->send();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Working fine.

Comment: Thanks for mark as a right answer. :)

Comment: @RaviSoni how to send email to multiple users can u advise?

Comment: Check now I have added array for variable $to

Comment: thanks @RaviSoni

Comment: Thanks, For upvote  :)

Comment: @RaviSoni can we execute this zend email concept on magento2 root folder?

Comment: I have tried this on Magento 2.3.1 but getting an error Fatal error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Zend_Mail' not found in /srv/public_html/pub/test.php

Comment: is there anything that needs to be included from my end?

Comment: can you guys help why I have error? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/326894/how-do-i-send-a-email-from-the-cron-job-magento-2

Answer (score 9):

Send email programmatically without email template, code is tested in Magento 2.4

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterfaceFactory
 */
protected $messageInterfaceFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterfaceFactory
 */
protected $mailTransportFactory;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterfaceFactory $messageInterfaceFactory
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterfaceFactory $mailTransportFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterfaceFactory $messageInterfaceFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterfaceFactory $mailTransportFactory
) {
    $this->messageInterfaceFacory = $messageInterfaceFactory;
    $this->mailTransportFactory = $mailTransportFactory;
}

public function execute()
{
    $from = 'noreply@test.com';
    $to = 'test@gmail.com';
    $subject = "email subject";
    $emailHtml = "<h1>Test Email</h1>";

    try {
        $message = $this->messageInterfaceFactory->create();
        $message->setFromAddress($from);
        $message->addTo($to);
        $message->setSubject($subject);
        $message->setBodyHtml($emailHtml);
        $transport = $this->mailTransportFactory->create(['message' => $message]);
        $transport->sendMessage();

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo "error=>".$e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Working good... :)

Comment: Need to be changed in the constructor messageInterfaceFacory -> messageInterfaceFactory because it produces an error.

Answer (score 4):

You can send mail using `Zend_Mail()` function.

```
$firstname = "xxx";
$lastname = "yyyyyy";

// Send Mail functionality starts from here 
$from = "from_address@example.com";
$nameFrom = "From Name";
$to = "to_address@example.com";
$nameTo = "To Name";
$body = "
<div>
    <b>".$firstname."</b>
    <i>".$lastname."</i>
</div>";

$email = new \Zend_Mail();
$email->setSubject("Email Subject"); 
$email->setBodyHtml($body);     // use it to send html data
//$email->setBodyText($body);   // use it to send simple text data
$email->setFrom($from, $nameFrom);
$email->addTo($to, $nameTo);
$email->send();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Working fine.

Comment: I have tried this on Magento but getting an error Fatal error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Zend_Mail' not found in /srv/public_html/pub/test.php

Comment: Check zend-email installed or not? follow below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140870/zend-mail-class-zend-mail-message-not-found