# How do I send a email from the cron job? Magento 2 Unable to send mail

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, email, cron

I did create a cron job with custom sql query.  It will send an email notification to our support email. Can someone tell me what's wrong my email coding, from the log it said I am unable to send mail? I had mageplaza SMTP setup, I am able to send testing email by using gmail SMTP

```
            <?php
            namespace ABC\CheckAddress\Cron;
            
            use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
            
            class Test {
                protected $logger;
            
                public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger) {
                    $this->logger = $logger;
                }
            
               /**
                * Write to system.log
                *
                * @return void
                */
                public function execute() {
                    //$this->logger->info('Cron Works');
                    
                     $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
                     $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
                     $connection = $resource->getConnection();
                     $tableName = $resource->getTableName('sales_order_payment');
                     $attribute_information = "SELECT sales_order_payment.additional_information FROM sales_order LEFT JOIN 
                        sales_order_payment ON sales_order.entity_id = sales_order_payment.parent_id 
                        WHERE sales_order_payment.method = 'ABCpayment' AND sales_order.updated_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH";
    
                    $results = $connection->fetchAll($attribute_information);    
            
                foreach ($results as $result) {
                    $json_array = implode($result);
                        $data = json_decode($json_array); 
                        $address_verification_json = $data->shipping_address_verification; 
                        $data2 = json_decode($address_verification_json);
                        $postal_code = $data2->postal_code;
                    
                    if ($postal_code < 1) {
                        
    /* How I send ?             
    SEND EMAIL TO CUSTOMER SERVICE  */


    $body = 'test';
    $from = 'Paul';
    $nameFrom = 'paul@gmail.com';
    $to = 'Paul';
    $nameTo = 'paul@gmail.com'';
    
    
$email = new \Zend_Mail();
$email->setSubject("Feedback email");
$email->setBodyText($body);
$email->setFrom($from, $nameFrom);
$email->addTo($to, $nameTo);
$email->send();
                    
/* it show unable to send mail
 am I missing something?    */
                    }
                 
                }
                }
            }
```

this is the error

```
   [2020-11-25 23:52:03] report.CRITICAL: Unable to send mail.  {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception(code: 0): Unable to send mail.  at /var/www/html/Magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php:111)"} []
```

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/298001/82670

Answer (score 0):

I finally manage to get the cron job running and able to send out email. I would like to share my code, if someone have the same problem in the future.

```
<?php


namespace ABC\CheckPay\Cron;

use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
class Test
{   
        /**
    * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
    */
    private $logger;
    /**
    * @var TransportBuilder
    */
    private $transportBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
    )
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
    }

    /**
    * Execute the cron
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function execute()
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
         $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
         $connection = $resource->getConnection();
         $tableName = $resource->getTableName('sales_order_payment');
         $attribute_information = "SELECT sales_order_payment.additional_information FROM sales_order LEFT JOIN 
            sales_order_payment ON sales_order.entity_id = sales_order_payment.parent_id 
            WHERE sales_order_payment.method = 'checkpay' AND sales_order.updated_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH";

        $results = $connection->fetchAll($attribute_information);
        
        
        

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $json_array = implode($result);
            $data = json_decode($json_array); 
            $address_verification_json = $data->shipping_address_verification; 
            $data2 = json_decode($address_verification_json);
            $postal_code = $data2->postal_code;
        
        if ($postal_code < 1) {
            

    
            try {
        $templateVars = [];
        $transport = $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('59')
        ->setTemplateOptions( [ 'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => 1 ] )
        ->setTemplateVars( $templateVars )
        ->setFrom( [ "name" => "Magento ABC CHECK PAYMENT", "email" => "paul@gmail.com" ] )
        ->addTo('paul@gmail.com')
        ->setReplyTo('paul@gmail.com')
        ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
        return $this;   
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error($e);
        }

            
        }
 

     
    }


        

    }

}
```